# CakePHP How to Persist Search Querystring to Subsequent Paginator Pages

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.6

I had a search page that filtered correctly, but when it paginated you would lose the data since I was POSTing it.  So I switched it to a GET, but I can't figure out how to add the http_build_query( $params ) that I passed back to the paginator.

I've tried setting query params in the paginator url in options, but with no luck and the API doesn't mention adding the query params.

How do I set the search results query params so the different pages know what they were being filtered on? So a search on name=steve and company=SomeCompany is maintained through page 2, 3, 4, with 10 results each, and doesn't reset to show all non-filtered 100 results.

**Simple Example Pagination in Controller**

```
$this->paginate = [
    'limit'      => 5,
    'order'      => [ 'CollectionAgencyAgent.id' => 'desc' ]
];

return $this->paginate( $this->CollectionAgencyAgent, $conditions );
```

**VIEW with Pagination**

```
<ul class="pagination <?php echo $class ?>">

    <?php
    $this->Paginator->options( [
        'url' => [
            'controller' => ''
        ]
    ] );
    ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev( __( '&laquo; Previous' ), [
        'escape'      => false,
        'tag'         => 'li',
        'class'       => 'arrow',
        'disabledTag' => 'a'
    ] ); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers( [
        'separator'  => '',
        'tag'        => 'li',
        'currentTag' => 'a'
    ] ); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next( __( 'Next &raquo;' ), [
        'escape'      => false,
        'tag'         => 'li',
        'class'       => 'arrow',
        'disabledTag' => 'a'
    ] ); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paginator class [automatically merges the current request parameters](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php#L112-L115):

```
public function beforeRender($viewFile) {
    $this->options['url'] = array_merge($this->request->params['pass'], $this->request->params['named']);
    if (!empty($this->request->query)) {
        $this->options['url']['?'] = $this->request->query;
    }
    parent::beforeRender($viewFile);
}
```

So the short answer is to do nothing, and that'll just work.

The reason it doesn't work with the code in the question is that this call:

```
$this->Paginator->options( [
    'url' => [
        'controller' => ''
    ]
] );
```

Which will wipe out the Paginator's run time url options. So, to prevent the problem in the question - just delete that call (and then, probably fix the routing problem which prompted you to add it =)).

Comment: Thanks, yah our routes look... funky to say the least I'll have to figure out what they did there so we stop getting page not found now that I've removed the options you mentioned.

Comment: Related to my Route issue it appears to be due to use not wanting the controller in the the URL for the main routes `Router::connect( '/:action/*', [ 'controller' => 'sales', 'pass' => $subdomain ] );` where subdomain is `
`$subdomain = substr( env( "HTTP_HOST" ), 0, strpos( env( "HTTP_HOST" ), "." ) );` since we're on the sales domains `sales.ourdomain.com` so didn't want `sales.ourdomain.com/sales/action...`, but paginator wants to use `/sales/action/page:2`.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I ended up making a question out of this if you're intereseted http://stackoverflow.com/q/32918085/1148107